# Desktop.setOpenFileHandler doesn't work when program isn't running

Tags: java, macos, javafx, file-association

I'm making a program for mac that has it's own file extension `.edul`. I got it working so that when the program has already opened and you open the file it's load it, but when I try this when the program is yet running I don't get the event and it's not in the args.

I tried to change to `com.apple.eawt.Application` but unfortunately `java.desktop` doesn't export this class so this didn't work.

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.setOpenFileHandler(e -> {
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/test.txt");
        fileWriter.write(e.getFiles().toString());
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
});
```

So I expect a file on my desktop that has the location of the file I opened before the program was running and when it's running and I open another file it's also shows on my desktop.

So after first file open:
`[file/path/test.edul]`

And on seconds file open:
`[file/path/test2.edul]`

I'm currently only getting:
`[file/path/test2.edul]`

Comment: Are you asking why the handler isn't working when the java app isn't running?

Comment: When opening the program with a file the handler doesn't register the event I think.

Comment: I am guessing this has something to do with setting the file association on mac/choosing the default program of a file extension on mac? You not can expect Java code to run if the application is not running.

Comment: The the program starts when i open `test.edul` but I cant find the file where it was opened with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that when you define a `FileOpenHandler` in the class which starts your fx application the `FileOpenEvent` is only thrown when the program is already running. So you should make a other main class that doesn't extends `Application` and the `FileOpenEvent` will be correctly thrown even when the application is still starting up.